# Powershell script only running in ISE

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, cmd

Running a script that starts and kills/cleans two jobs via batch file before I package it for an EXE, works great in ISE elevated but immediately fails in console or command prompt with the following:

[image: Error]

The code I have put together is here: https://pastebin.com/FWaZD249

- I tested it with:

  1. PS1 to EXE, get the same results
  2. Non-elevated ISE same results
  3. Elevated console same results
  4. Elevated CMD same results
  5. Elevated ISE works (only after saving?)

It's really close to being done, basically, it's just a little script that checks the 5900 port for established connections, updates a form of a list of connections, and sends a little notification if someone new has connected, it runs on our print server computer which is screen-shared remotely via TightVNC, so operators don't get surprised when their mouse starts moving on them.

cmd batch code looks like this

```
powershell.exe -NoExit ". C:\Users\VS-Print-Server\Desktop\Userchecker.PS1"
```

Comment: For your cmd/batch code, `%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -File "C:\Users\VS-Print-Server\Desktop\Userchecker.ps1"` is what I'd suggest. I have no idea what your `.` was supposed to be for, because it looks as if you intended it to be related to the current directory, which should already be the case.

Comment: I've always found the strange differences between ISE execution and normal powershell execution to be extremely peculiar. I would love to know why this occurs even if it's in this scenario :D

Comment: if you run "  get-job FormJob |receive-job "    Do you get an error exception ?

Comment: you initialize the jobs `$job1` and `job2` with `$FormLib` respectively `$LisLib` before those variables are set. I assume you just have to put line 1 through 30 (everything before `Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Before:';` at the very end to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment: you initialize the jobs `$job1` and `job2` with `$FormLib` respectively `$LisLib` before those variables are set/initialized. Moving line 1 through 30 (everything before `Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Before:'`) to the very end should make it work.